# What is $\tan x\cdot \tan y$ when given $\sin(x+y)=2/3$ and $\sin(x-y)=-1/3$?

Tags: trigonometry

I tried solving it by using the formulas for $\sin(x+y)$ and $\sin(x-y)$ but I got stuck with $\tan y=6\tan x$.
I then tried another approach, using $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$ and found the values of $\cos(x+y)$ and $\cos(x-y)$. Then I wrote $\tan(x+y)$ and $\tan(x-y)$ with the extended formulas $(\tan x+\tan y)/(1-\tan x\tan y)$ and the one with $-$, and matched them with the formula $\tan(x+y)=\sin(x+y)/\cos(x+y)$ and the one with $-$ respectively, because above I calculated the values for the terms of the fraction. However, I only got $\tan x\tan y$ equalling a fraction containing $\tan x$ and $\tan y$, so got nowhere in the end. Any ideas? Sorry for the bulk of text, it’s my first post and thanks in advance!

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) so that `$\sin(x+y)$` $\to \sin(x+y)$.

Comment: Please expand terms and add /subtract. For example $\cos(x+y) = \cos x \cos y - \sin x \sin y$. If you find $\sin x \sin y$ and $\cos x \cos y$, you are done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**
$$\cos(x+y)=\cos x \cos y - \sin x \sin y$$
$$\cos(x-y)=\cos x \cos y + \sin x \sin y$$
Sum both equations and get

$$2\cos x \cos y=\cos(x+y)+\cos(x-y).\quad (1)$$

Subtract both equations and get

$$2\sin x \sin y=\cos(x-y)-\cos(x+y).\quad (2)$$

Divide $(2)$ by $(1)$ and get $\tan x\cdot\tan y$.

Comment: Thank you very much!